# Hierarchical Clustering: Extract observations from large heatmap

Tags: python, scikit-learn, seaborn

I'm currently trying to visualize a large data set as heat map. That in itself works smoothly but I struggle with gaining insights from interestingly looking clusters.

Specifically, I have two questions that are very related:

First, I find clusters of interesting features and am looking for a systematic way to extract the a flat clustering at a specific level (but the [fcluster](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster) function seems to do something different and [cut_tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree.html) doesn't work with those trees). I would like to have a slice of the hierarchical clustering at a specified depth of the dendrogram. This is probably encoded in the linkage matrix `Z` but I struggle to understand how exactly I can extract that information from `Z`.

Second, with the complicated heatmap pictured below, the row names on the right are gene names for every 100th data point (gene). I would now like to have a look at which genes are in some of the little clusters, for instance the little black square for feature `MF: LIHC` that is marked.
[image: heatmap with interesting features]
I know the IDs of the genes that are labelled on the right, so I would want to know something like:

*Which genes are in the same cluster as CAPN7 at level 5?*

Thank you for your help!

Roman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869640/alternative-to-scipy-cluster-hierarchy-cut-tree) was asked at stackoverflow. There it was proposed to use the option `criterion='maxclust'` for the `flcuster` function:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
clust = fcluster(Z, t=k, criterion='maxclust')
```

The description of this option in the flcuster documentation is a bit confusing, but that's how you get a clustering with `t=k` clusters.

You should be able to retrieve the answer to your second question with the resulting array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are referring to in Q1, but for Q2, it looks like you are trying to dig down to the lower negative correlated items, right.  I can't reproduce your exace example (I don't have the data), but I will give you a generic example, which you can easily adapt to your specific scenario.

```
# get only numerics from your dataframe; correlations work on values not labels
df = df.sample(frac=0.1, replace=True, random_state=1)
numerics = ['int16', 'int32', 'int64', 'float16', 'float32', 'float64']
newdf = df.select_dtypes(include=numerics)

for col in newdf.columns: 
    print(col) 

# Compute the correlation matrix
# no statistically significant correlations between any numeric features...
corrmat = newdf.corr()
top_corr_features = corrmat.index
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
#plot heat map
g=sns.heatmap(newdf[top_corr_features].corr(),annot=True,cmap="RdYlGn")
```

[image]

```
# Identify Highly Negatively Correlated Features
# Create correlation matrix
corr_matrix = newdf.corr()
# Select upper triangle of correlation matrix
upper = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
# Find index of feature columns with correlation less than 0
to_keep = [column for column in upper.columns if any(upper[column] < 0)]
```

Answer: `['rating', 'num_comments', 'list_price', 'lowest_price_new_condition']`

Finally, let's say you want to drop everything that has >.2 correlation, and keep only the non-correlated features or negatively correlated features, you can do this...

```
# Create correlation matrix
corr_matrix = newdf.corr()
# Select upper triangle of correlation matrix
upper = corr_matrix.where(np.triu(np.ones(corr_matrix.shape), k=1).astype(np.bool))
# Find index of feature columns with correlation greater than 0.95
to_drop = [column for column in upper.columns if any(upper[column] > .2)]
# Drop features 
finaldf = newdf.drop(newdf[to_drop], axis=1)

corrmat = finaldf.corr()
top_corr_features = corrmat.index
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
#plot heat map
g=sns.heatmap(finaldf[top_corr_features].corr(),annot=True,cmap="RdYlGn")
```

[image]